# Multiple forms problem

Tags: html, forms

I have 2 forms one after another, but the second one is not posting at all. Everything works fine except the submitting. Can I have 2 forms like this?

```
 <form action="getRates.php" name="rates" method="post" onSubmit="popupform(this, 'join')">
                          <table style="width: 216px">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width: 115px; height: 49px;"><span class="style16">Weight</span><br/>
                                  <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" size="10" maxlength="4"/>
                                  <input type="hidden" id="weightOne" name ="weightOne">
                                  <input type="hidden" id="weightTwo" name ="weightTwo">
                                  <input type="hidden" id="weightThree" name="weightThree">
                                  <input type="hidden" id="weightFour" name="weightFour">
                              </td>
                              <td align="right" style="width: 68px; height: 49px;" valign="top"><span class="style16">Zip Code</span><br/>
                                  <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" size="10" maxlength="5"/>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width: 115px">
                              <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Door Hanger Rates" style="width: 138px" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          </form>
                         <form action="getBusinessRates.php" name="businessRates" method="post" onSubmit="popupform(this, 'join')">
                          <table style="width: 216px">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width: 115px; height: 49px;"><span class="style16">Weight</span><br/>
                                  <input type="text" id="businessWeight" name="businessWeight" size="10" maxlength="4" />
                              </td>
                              <td align="right" style="width: 68px; height: 49px;" valign="top"><span class="style16">Zip Code</span><br/>
                                  <input type="text" id="businessZip" name="businessZip" size="10" maxlength="5" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="width: 115px">
                              <input name="businessSubmit" type="submit" value="Business Card Rates" style="width: 138px" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                         </form>
```

Comment: you really shouldn't be nesting a form inside a form?

Comment: He isn't, the first </form> is before the second <form>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your same code is working, [you can check it out here](http://jsbin.com/opice3). It might be some other issue probably.

Comment: That is weird. The second submit button is not working at all on my page

Comment: DOCTYPE could be the possible issue also but i am not 100% sure. Check to see what are you using.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> this?